# How to share an internet connection between two VLAN?

Tags: internet-connection, switch, vlan

How to share an internet connection between two VLAN?
(If it's possible)

Let's say a single internet connection (Asus RT-AC87U router) that I want it to serve 192.168.1.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/24 VLAN on the same switch (HP 1820-24G Switch J9980A).

Comment: If you wish to maintain the security of the VLANs you can connect by a low cost VPN system

Comment: That switch supports VLANs, but that is not your problem. Your router needs to support VLANs too. Without support on the router side you can never make this work. Please EDIT your question and add details on what router you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you need *some* router between your VLANs.

You could use an L3 switch (the HPE 1820 is L2 only), or a VLAN-capable router (the RT-AC87U might do, can't say for sure).

With a router, you need to trunk the VLANs from the switch to the router. On the switch, configure both VLANs as 802.1q-tagged towards the router (one "native" VLAN may stay untagged if you prefer). On the router, create a virtual subinterface for each VLAN (tagging needs to mirror the switch config). If everything's done correctly, a client from each VLAN should be able to ping its default gateway.

Comment: I apologize; I am a newbie. How do I "trunk the VLANs from the switch"? How do I "create a virtual sub-interface"? Do you mean, that I have to connect 2 cables from the Router to the Switch (One for each VLAN on the Switch) & trunk the 2 cables on the Router?

Comment: "trunking VLANs" means configure an interface with multiple, tagged VLANs. You need to configure the VLANs first and then add the desired interfaces as untagged ("access ports" for normal devices) or tagged (to form a VLAN trunk towards VLAN-aware devices).

Comment: I think I can't configure my router as you describe. So, it will have to wait for my next router.